# Allure Jenkins plugin giving error while generating report

Tags: java, jenkins-pipeline, allure

I have installed the latest Allure plugins in Jenkins server.
That specific code when it tries to generate allure report, it has thrown me the following error

> 

```
[Pipeline] { (Generate Report)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] allure
Unable to auto-install JDK until the license is accepted.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // ws
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisherDescriptor.getCommandlineInstallation(AllureReportPublisherDescriptor.java:112)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher.getCommandline(AllureReportPublisher.java:346)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher.generateReport(AllureReportPublisher.java:303)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher.perform(AllureReportPublisher.java:231)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:101)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: issue is with JDK installation not with Allure Plugin. were you able to resolve this ?

Comment: yes it is resolved